# Haskell Error "Not in scope: data constructor"

Tags: haskell

I've reviewed the other posts on this error, and I don't think I'm making any of those mistakes.

Not in scope: data constructor 'Extraction'.

Configuration.hs:

```
module Configuration
(Config
 , columns
 , headers
 , types
 , totals
 , extractions,
 Extraction
 , xState
 , xDivisions
 , xOffice
 ...) where

...

data Extraction = Extraction { xState     :: String
                             , xDivisions :: Maybe [String]
                             , xOffice    :: Maybe String } deriving Show


data Config = Config { columns     ::  String
                     , headers     :: [String]
                     , types       :: [String]
                     , totals      :: [String]
                     , extractions :: [Extraction] } deriving Show

...
```

PIF.hs:

```
module PIF (...) where

import Configuration

...

data Report = Report { division  :: String
                     , state     :: String
                     , office    :: String
                     , inSection :: Bool
                     , content   :: [String] } deriving Show

...

extract :: Config -> [Report] -> [Report]
extract c = filter f
  where f Report { division=d, state=s, office=o, inSection=_, content=_ } =
          map or $ map isMatch $ extractions c
          where isMatch
                  | Extraction { xState=xS, xDivisions=Just xD, xOffice=Nothing } = s==xS && (map or $ map (==d) xD)
                  | Extraction { xState=xS, xDivisions=Nothing, xOffice=Just xO } = s==xS && o==xO
```

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Here is my corrected `extract`:

```
extract c = filter f
  where f Report { division=d, state=s, office=o, inSection=_, content=_ } =
          or $ map isMatch $ extractions c
          where isMatch x =
                  case ((xDivisions x), (xOffice x)) of (Nothing, Just y) -> s==(xState x) && o==y
                                                        (Just y, Nothing) -> s==(xState x) && (or $ map (==d) y)
```

Comment: This error also covered the fact that I was using pattern syntax in an expression context. I changed the `Extraction {xState=xS...}` to a `case` statement. I also removed the incorrect `map`s over `or`. `or` reduces a list, it doesn't map over it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the export line `Extraction` to `Extraction(..)`.

Without that, you're exporting the type but not the data constructor. Since your type and constructor share the same name, this is less than obvious in this case.

Comment: Holy cow! Thank you so much! I never would have figured that out on my own. :)